# How to use LottieAnimationView in SharedElementTransition?

Tags: kotlin

I decided to use Lottie animation to switch from activity to activity.
My animation covers the entire screen, and I would like to have half the animation time played on the first activity and the rest on the second activity

I tried using Shared Element Transition but it doesn't work properly because when new activity starts first what i see is new activity and then after few miliseconds Lottie animation resumes. I would like to avoid showing new activity before Lottie animation is over

First Activity XML file

```xml
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                           android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                           android:id="@+id/newActivityAnimation"
                                           app:lottie_fileName="transitionAnimation.json"
                                           android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                                           android:elevation="5dp"
                                           android:transitionName="sharedNewActivityTransition"

    />
```

Second Activity XML file

```xml
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.MenuActivity">

    <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                           android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                           app:lottie_fileName="transitionAnimation.json"
                                           android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                                           android:id="@+id/changeActivityAnimationMenu"
                                           android:elevation="5dp"
                                           android:transitionName="sharedNewActivityTransition"

    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is function which start changing activite

```
   override fun onLanguageClickListener(position: Int) {
        animateCollapseMenuSlide(isMenuCollapsed)
        newActivityAnimation.setMaxFrame(19)
        delay.delayedFunction({newActivityAnimation.playAnimation()},200)
        delay.delayedFunction({changeActivity()},1000)


    }


.
.
.


 private fun changeActivity() {
        val intent = Intent(this,MenuActivity::class.java)
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION
        val options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this,activityTransitionAnimation,
            "sharedNewActivityTransition")
        startActivity(intent,options.toBundle())
    }
```